# errno=-32 is showing up on installation of ubuntu 12

Tags: installation, macbook-pro

I get Errno=-32 when trying to instal ubuntu 12 on a macbook pro. Is there some one that can tell me what errno=-32 means?

Comment: I guess it is a [**Reported Bug here**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/968216)

Answer (score 0):

Errno 32 is: EPIPE, Broken pipe. So I suspect a process that is reading or writing on the pipe died unexpectedly and caused this error message. How it relates to the install is hard to tell without further details.